# Automation for SQL schema changes on AWD RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, database-migration, awsdeploy

We are using SQL DB for our application and these both are hosted on AWS. We have already setup CI/CD pipeline for application as per environment.

So, my question is how can we automate SQL schema changes using AWS? I know there are lot of third party tools are available in the marked, but is it possible using AWS managed services?

Thanks for the help !